# How to pass access token from backed to frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, access-token

I'm developing app (FE: Vue.js, BE: flask), and I want to know how to pass access token from BE to FE.

This is my auth.py (BE) file, and I store access token to payload.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
import json
from functools import wraps
from jose import jwt
from urllib.request import urlopen


app = Flask(__name__)

AUTH0_DOMAIN = ***
ALGORITHMS = ['RS256']
API_AUDIENCE = ***


class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error, status_code):
        self.error = error
        self.status_code = status_code


def get_token_auth_header():
    """Obtains the Access Token from the Authorization Header
    """
    auth = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)
    print(request.headers)
    if not auth:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'authorization_header_missing',
            'description': 'Authorization header is expected.'
        }, 401)

    parts = auth.split()
    if parts[0].lower() != 'bearer':
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization header must start with "Bearer".'
        }, 401)

    elif len(parts) == 1:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Token not found.'
        }, 401)

    elif len(parts) > 2:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization header must be bearer token.'
        }, 401)

    token = parts[1]
    return token


def verify_decode_jwt(token):
    jsonurl = urlopen(f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    rsa_key = {}
    if 'kid' not in unverified_header:
        raise AuthError({
            'code': 'invalid_header',
            'description': 'Authorization malformed.'
        }, 401)

    for key in jwks['keys']:
        if key['kid'] == unverified_header['kid']:
            rsa_key = {
                'kty': key['kty'],
                'kid': key['kid'],
                'use': key['use'],
                'n': key['n'],
                'e': key['e']
            }
    if rsa_key:
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token,
                rsa_key,
                algorithms=ALGORITHMS,
                audience=API_AUDIENCE,
                issuer='https://' + AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/'
            )

            return payload

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'token_expired',
                'description': 'Token expired.'
            }, 401)

        except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_claims',
                'description': 'Incorrect claims. Please, check the audience and issuer.'
            }, 401)
        except Exception:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Unable to parse authentication token.'
            }, 400)
    raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Unable to find the appropriate key.'
            }, 400)
def check_permissions(permission, payload):
    if 'permissions' not in payload:
        print(payload)
        abort(400)
    if permission not in payload['permissions']:
        print(permission)
        abort(403)
    return True

def requires_auth(permission=''):
    def requires_auth_decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            token = get_token_auth_header()
            try:
                payload = verify_decode_jwt(token)
            except:
                abort(401)
            check_permissions(permission, payload)

            return f(payload, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return requires_auth_decorator
```

This is my FE code. currently, I store static data to accessToken so I want to make it dynamically. I don't know how to get accessToken from BE..

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'ActorList',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      actorList: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const accessToken = '***';
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/actor-list`,{
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.actorList = response.data.actor;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("There was an error!", error);
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The access token is produced during the login then the server sends the token and the necessary data, after that you can store the token in local storage or http only cookies  finally you can access the token and send it in the header.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).